# Can I publish two apps with the same code on iOS and Android market?

Tags: android, ios

I developed a directory app for my city (for both iOS and Android). Another city wants to have the same app for their city. The content will obviously be different but the code will be the same (may be some minor changes). Will Google Play Market and iTunes allow me to publish the second app?

Comment: I don’t know about iOS, but for android you have to just change the package name, and it will allow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably yes, but I would recommend you make some kind of settings in your app to allow users to choose the city.

But read the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/):

> **2.20** Developers "spamming" the App Store with many versions of similar Apps will be removed from the iOS Developer Program

I have an experience posting two apps with the similar functionality in the AppStore within one Developer program but there was different icons, description, little bit different design etc and also know person which successfully did the same in the Google Play